# $2^x = 6 * 2^x -10?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need help to solve 
$$
2^x = 6 \cdot 2^x -10
$$

The book tells me to simplify to $-5 \cdot 2^x = -10$
I don't know how to do that
Can anyone help me?
The answer is $x = 1$
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKvZO.png)

Comment: Lets take things slower.  Rather than $\color{blue}{2^x}=6\cdot \color{blue}{2^x}-10$, can you start out with $\color{blue}{y}=6\cdot \color{blue}{y}-10$ and solve for $y$?  Do you see why this is essentially the first steps to completing your original problem?

Answer (score 4):

HINT

Treat the $2^x$ as a variable $y$ ... so you get $y =6y-10$ ... can you take it from there?

Comment: Wow thanks! But I want to know how to do this without substitutions, I'd really appreciate it if you would tell me how to do this without substitutions :)

Comment: Substitutions only serve to make the _same_ arithmetic simpler.

Comment: You do it exactly the same with substitutions as you do without substitutions.  You just recognize, hey I've got a blue thing on the left side of $\color{blue}{2^x}=6\cdot \color{blue}{2^x}-10$ and the same blue thing on the right side, so I can manipulate them like I hope since they are the same blue thing.  It doesn't matter how complicated or simple of an expression each of the blue things are... all that matters here was that they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

To get from $2^x=6\cdot2^x-10$ to $-5\cdot2^x=-10$, you merely subtract $6\cdot2^x$ from both sides, which initially gives $2^x-6\cdot2^x=-10$, and then use the fact that $2^x-6\cdot2^x=(1-6)2^x=-5\cdot2^x$.

Do you need any further help, or was that the only step that had you puzzled?

Comment: Yeah that was the only step that had me puzzled, thank you so much man!!

Answer (score 0):

It is simple

$$2^x-6*2^x=-10$$

Common out $2^x$
$$2^x(1-6)=-10$$

$$-5*2^x=-10$$

Divide whole equation by -5

$$2^x=2 $$

You can write 2 as $ 2^1$

So $x=1$